# Which of the following inputs is correct for the desired operation?

Tags: syntax, formatting

sorry for another (very likely) dumb question, but I'm having trouble telling which of the following (if either) yields the desired operation.

What I'd like is to define a function:
$$ud = u(f/2) - \sum_{i=0}^{f-1}\left(g\left(\sum_{j=0}^{i}p_{j}\right)\left[u\left(i+1-\frac{f}{2}\right)-u\left(i-\frac{f}{2}\right)\right]\right)$$
Where:
$u(x)=x$ (I know including it as a function just complicates things, but I'd like to be able to change it to a more complex function later) and $g(p_{j})$ is a function of the probability of receiving j heads in f flips of a fair coin. The two versions I have for this are:

`ud[fp_, u_, prob_, f_] :=  u[(f/2)] - Sum[fp[Sum[prob[j, f], {j, 0, i}]] (u[(-f/2 + i + 1)] - u[(-f/2 + i)]), {i, 0, f - 1}]
ud2[fp_, u_, prob_, f_] := u[(f/2)] - Sum[fp[prob[j, f]] (u[(i + 1 - f/2)] - u[(i - f/2)]), {i, 0, f - 1}, {j, 0, i}]`

(To assist with running them, the rest of the code is:

```
Clear[prob, h, f, fp, u, z, ud, dn, dnf, uc, cn, cnf, comb, ud2, dnf2]
(* The code below solves c^n/n for the Second Part *)
u[z_] := z
prob[h_, f_] := (f!/(h! (f - h)!))/(2^f)
uc[prob_, u_, f_] := Sum[prob[i, f] u[(-f/2 + i)], {i, 0, f}]
cn[uc_] := uc
cnf[uc_, f_] := uc/f
N[cnf[uc[prob, u, 100], 100]] 
(* The code below solves d^n/n for the Second Part *)
u[z_] := z
prob[h_, f_] := (f!/(h! (f - h)!))/(2^f)
fp[prob_] := prob^.5
ud[fp_, u_, prob_, f_] := u[(f/2)] - Sum[fp[Sum[prob[j, f], {j, 0, i}]] u[(-f/2 + i + 1)] - u[(-f/2 + i)]), {i, 0, f - 1}]
ud2[fp_, u_, prob_, f_] := u[(f/2)] - Sum[fp[prob[j, f]] (u[(i + 1 - f/2)] - u[(i - f/2)]), {i, 0, f - 1}, {j, 0, i}]
dn[ud_] := ud
dnf[ud_, f_] := ud/f
dnf2[ud2_, f_] := ud2/f
N[dnf[ud[fp, u, prob, 100], 100]]
N[dnf2[ud2[fp, u, prob, 100], 100]]
```

I'm sure I accidentally left out necessary information, so please let me know and I'll try to fix the question!

EDIT NOTE 10:54AM EST: I realized I accidentally included an extra "+1" term in the second u function in the code, which has been removed

Thanks!!!

Comment: For the record, the larger block of code calculates a few other things that aren't necessarily included in the question, but I pasted the entire block just in case. The comments are for the larger code workbook, and aren't related to this stack exchange question specifically. Sorry about any confusion!!

Comment: Since you want the sum inside your function `g` (which is really just `g=fp`?), you want the first one.  In the second version, you've pulled the sum over `j` outside of `g`.  Note that you could check this yourself by plugging in some sample values.  (E.g., `u[fp,u,prob,3]`, or use generic functions `u[ffp,uu,pp,3]`, which might make the structure of the sum more explicit.)